# Converting IP address to binary

Tags: c++

I'm currently working on converting each piece of an ip address to binary, and I would be glad if u can tell me why my code doesn't work. The main problem is with function ip_bin(); cause it's converting the first number correctly to binary but somehow later then it is adding the first number to the second one... same situation in 2 last answers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string ip, mask;
string ip_string[4];
int ip_int[4], length[4];

void enter();
void get_ip();
void ip_bin();

int main(){

    enter();
    get_ip();
    ip_bin();

return 0;}

void enter(){

    cout<<"Enter ip adress: ";
    cin>>ip;
    cout<<"Enter mask adress: ";
    cin>>mask;
}

void get_ip(){
//splitting to sections each number between the ip dots 
    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){

        ip_int[i] = stoi(ip.substr(0, '.'));
        cout<<ip_int[i]<<endl;
        string z = to_string(ip_int[i]);
        int ln = z.length();
        ip.erase(0, ln+1);
    }
}

void ip_bin(){
    int i=0, tab[31];
    for(int k = 0; k<4; k++){
        while(ip_int[k]){
            tab[i++] = ip_int[k]%2;

            ip_int[k] = ip_int[k]/2;
        }
        for(int j = i-1; j>=0; j--){
            ip_string[k] = ip_string[k] + to_string(tab[j]);
        }

        length[k] = ip_string[k].length();
        if(length[k]<8){
            for(int g = 0; g<8 - length[k]; g++){
                ip_string[k] = '0' + ip_string[k];
            }
        }

        cout<<ip_string[k]<<endl;
    }


}
```

Comment: Okay, let me rephrase. get_ip is supposed to take the input string like 192.168.1.1 and convert it into a 4-byte array of 192, 168, 1, and 1, yes? Does it work? Next, ip_bin is trying to build ip_string as the binary representation of that array? Is that correct? If so, ip_bin's code looks really, really strange.

Comment: @JosephLarson with ip_bin() i was trying to prepare ground for calculating ip adress with given mask and ip. for 192.168.1.1 the first value 192 is getting converted to binary correctly: 11000000 but then with 168 im getting this kind of answer: 1100000010101000 and im curious why... the if(length[k]<8) is suppose to add zeros to create a full 8 byte array, then using mask (in binary) we can easily calculate ip adress

Comment: @JosephLarson and the get_ip function works

Comment: What is wrong with  1100000010101000? It is 192 followed by 168, in binary.

Comment: If you want only the 168 part, j >= 0 is what you should change. It should probably be j >= i - 8

Comment: @Cem ur sollution doesnt work :/ what im trying to fix is, for example: if we have an input like this: 1.1.1.1 i want to get an output:  00000001(endl) 00000001(endl) 00000001(endl) 00000001 but instead im getting an output like this:  00000001(endl) 00000011(endl) 00000111(endl) 00001111

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idk if u meant that but if its not what u wanted then comment i will delete , dont rep -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


string ip, mask;
string ip_string[4];
int ip_int[4], length[4];
void dec();
void enter();
void get_ip();
void ip_bin();

int main(){

    enter();
    get_ip();
    cout <<endl;
    dec();

return 0;}

void enter(){

    cout<<"Enter ip adress: ";
    cin>>ip;
}

void get_ip(){
//splitting to sections each number between the ip dots
    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){

        ip_int[i] = stoi(ip.substr(0, '.'));
        cout<<ip_int[i]<<" ";
        string z = to_string(ip_int[i]);
        int ln = z.length();
        ip.erase(0, ln+1);
    }
}

void  dec() {
 int bin =0;
 int i=1;
 for(int  s=0; s<4; s++)
 {
     while(ip_int[s] >0 ){
  bin += (ip_int[s]%2)*i;
  ip_int[s] = ip_int[s]/2;
  i*=10;
 }
 cout <<bin<<endl;
 bin = 0;
 i=1;
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you rep + and enter my post ?